# Why does asp.net running on .net 4.8 add a http header x-aspnet-version: 4.0.30319

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I do have .net 4.8 installed. When i create a new simple asp.net mvc application using visual studio 2019 and start the website using the builtin IIS-Express, it will add the following header:

- x-aspnet-version: 4.0.30319

The same header is also added when i'm hosting the site using IIS. I am aware that i can remove this header (and i will), but i would like to understand the version number. 
It seems version 4.0.30319 was the initial .net 4.0 version number. What is the point to have this in the http header when using .net 4.8?

Comment: ASP.NET != .NET

Comment: From wikipedia: The ASP.NET releases history tightly correlates with the .NET Framework releases:

Comment: They are not the same software and have different version history though...

Comment: I'm unable to find the asp.net version history. Could you please provide a link to it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework_version_history, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_Core#Release_history, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET#Versions

Comment: This are the links i was referring to. But they don't have any information about 4.0.30319

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is the [CLR version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed).

- All .NET Framework 4 versions use CLR 4.0.30319.xxxxx
- xxxxx is less than 42000 for .NET Frameworks 4 to 4.5.2
- xxxxx is greater than 42000 for .NET Frameworks 4.6 and higher

The xxxxx extension is not part of the header for security purposes, so as not to divulge the patch state of the server.